# PHP delete row from a table with button click

Tags: php, html

I'm having problem to pass the id of the button to delete the row according to the id. What should i do to pass the id correctly?

```
   <form method="POST" >
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>Matric Number</th>
                        <th>IC Number</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysqli_error());
                        mysqli_select_db($link,"myDataBase") or die(mysqli_error());
                        $query="Select * From student" or die(mysqli_error());
                        $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

                        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["matric"]."</td><td>".$row["ic"]."</td>
                            <td><input type=button value=Update></td><td><input type=submit value=Delete name=delete ><input type=hidden name=id value=".$row["id"]." ></td></tr>";     
                        }   
                        }else{  
                            die("0 results");
                        }
                        if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
                            echo $did=$_POST['id'];
                            $query="Delete From student where id='$did'";
                            $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
                        }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that all hidden fields containing student IDs are placed inside one form. Therefor always last hidden field `ID` is posted when you click any delete button. Place your `form` tag inside `Delete` column for each row separately then only clicked row ID will be posted. Also place your `SELECT` query after `DELETE` query to refresh your HTML table immediately after delete. You also need to avoid SQL injection.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "" ) or die( mysqli_error() );
mysqli_select_db( $link, "myDataBase" ) or die( mysqli_error() );

// delete record
if( isset( $_POST['delete'] ) ) {

    echo $did = $_POST['id'];
    $query = $link->prepare( "DELETE FROM student WHERE id=?" );
    $query->bind_param( "s", $did );
    $query->execute();
}

// get all records
$query = "SELECT * FROM student" or die( mysqli_error() );
$result = mysqli_query( $link, $query );

?>

<table border="1">

    <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Matric Number</th>
        <th>IC Number</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

    <?php

        if( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

            while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["matric"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["ic"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><input type=button value=Update></td>";
                echo "<td><form method='POST'>
                <input type=hidden name=id value=".$row["id"]." >
                <input type=submit value=Delete name=delete >
                </form>
                </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

        } else {  
            die("0 results");
        }  
    ?>

</table>
```

You can also create delete links(i.e test.php?delete_id=100) for each row separately instead of creating `form` and `GET` ID to delete on server side.

Comment: Thanks a lot with your help, sir! But what do you mean with the delete links? Is it to create a test.php file and perform deletion at there?

Comment: `test.php` can be your current file with this code but method will changed from `POST` to `GET`. You have to use `$did = $_GET['id'];` to get the id of the record to be deleted. It is just a second option. Current version is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query:

```
 $query="Delete From student where id=$did";
```

instead

```
 $query="Delete From student where id='$did'";
```

Comment: If the `$did` is a integer it's quite bad to cast it into a string